# Combine column values based on the other column values in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let us say I have this data frame.

df

> ```
> line  to_line   priority
> 10    20          1
> 10    30          1
> 50    40          3
> 60    70          2
> 50    80          3
> ```

Based on the **line** and **priority** column values (when the are the same or duplicate as shown above), I want to combine **to_line** values. 
The proposed result should look like the following.

> ```
> line  to_line    priority
> 10        20/30         1
> 50        40/80         3
> 60         70           2
> ```

I tried something like this but I couldn't get what I want.

```
df.groupBy(col("line")).agg(collect_list(col("to_line")) as "to_line").withColumn("to_line", concat_ws(",", col("to_line")))
```

Could you please help to figure out this? I appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: if the last line will be 100  80 3 ?

Comment: Please include your data as text rather than images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by custom aggregation function.

**Code**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'line': [10,10,50,60,50],
    'to_line': [20,30,40,70,80],
    'priority': [1,1,3,2,3] 
})

array_agg = lambda x: '/'.join(x.astype(str))

grp_df = df.groupby(['line', 'priority']).agg({'to_line': array_agg})
```

, or if you do not want grouped columns to be indexes, you can pass `as_index` argument to `groupby`method

```
grp_df = df.groupby(['line', 'priority'], as_index=False).agg({'to_line': array_agg})
```

**Output**

```
              to_line
line priority        
10   1          20/30
50   3          40/80
60   2             70
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
res = []
df.to_line = df.to_line.astype(str)
for line_priority, df_chunk in df.groupby(['line','priority']):
    df_chunk = df_chunk.reset_index().sort_values('to_line')
    to_line = "/".join(df_chunk.to_line.values)
    res.append({'to_line':to_line,'priority':line_priority[1],'line':line_priority[0]})
pd.DataFrame(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
df.groupby(['line','priority'])['to_line'].apply(lambda x: '/'.join(str(y) for y in x)).reset_index(name='to_line')
```

**output**

```
  line  priority    to_line
0   10        1     20/30
1   50        3     40/80
2   60        2     70
```